# Smallest circle containing a point and two other circles

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

In 2D space, I have a point $P$ at $(P_x, P_y)$ and two circles A and B with centers $(A_x, A_y)$ and $(B_x, B_y)$ and radii $A_r$ and $B_r$. I want to find the smallest circle $C$ that fully contains $P$, $A$ and $B$.

Of course, the difficulty lies only in finding the center; the radius can then be obtained trivially.

It seems like super simple geometry, but I'm having difficulties finding a solution. One problem is that there are different cases: $C$ does not necessarily have to touch $P$, $A$ and $B$. It could be touching only two, or even be equal to $A$ or $B$ (tho that case is easy to check for separately).

[Geogebra Playground](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/j7sambmx)

[image]

Comment: This is  a case of Apollonius' Problem, see here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PCC.shtml